# CSS:I need to arrange < div > s in a very specific way but can't figure it out (look at the image)

Tags: html, css, position

I made this drawing to explain:

http://rdt.org.ni/here/for_stackoverflow.png

All the squares are `<div>`'s. The divs with same color belong to the same parent div. The yellow and green divs are ok. The problem is that the content div's height can vary, and I need the red div to stay ALWAYS alongside the "6" square, as in the drawing, but the content div's height keeps me from doing it because if it grows, the red div goes down and vice-versa (but the content div's height never goes further than the "6" square).

On the other hand, the green div's height may vary too, so giving the red div an absolute position won't fix it. I need the red div to "follow" always the "6" square. I've tried many ways without success.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

IMPORTANT EDIT:

Ok, ok, ok! Sorry! I apologize!! I see I got to give more detail!! Here is the tricky thing: The layout I drew is only for the home page! the yellow an red divs will disappear on any page else than home, only the green div and the content will stay (That's why the content will never go further, that's just on the home page, on the other pages it does go further). Therefore, I cannot make a table, or put the "6" square in a div with the red ones.

Comment: You say colors belong to the same parent, but I would pull the 3 bottom `div`s out and into the same container, then position the container relatively in such a way that it rests at the bottom of the right or left columns, whichever is taller.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<table>`?! Then all the `<td>` elements in the various rows stay associated with each other properly and if one grows in height it will push down and keep the proper association. Sometimes it is just not worthy fighting with the html/css to make it work when a `<table>` will do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a div inside the other div for the content like so

```
<div id="content_out">
    <div id="content_in">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the Css

```
#content_out{
//set the exact size
width:
height:}
#content_in{
//the size inside here can vary}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap the 7, 8, and 6 `div`'s in a parent `div`, and then `float` that left or right?

Then, pop a `clear:both` on `div 5`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="7"></div>
    <div id="8"></div>
    <div id="6"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#5 {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty approach, assuming the content of the blue div never exceeds the height of divs 4+5 (which is not a good approach if the content is truly dynamic/variable).

Not a good solution for actual use, but you can see one approach:

CSS

```
#outer_wrapper { position: relative; width: 700px; margin: 20px auto; background-color: gray; }

#yellow div { background-color: yellow; text-align: center; }
#blue { background-color: blue; text-align: center; }
#green div { background-color: green; text-align: center; }
#red div { background-color: red; text-align: center; }

#yellow div { float: left; width: 220px; margin: 0 20px 20px 0; }
#blue { clear: left; width: 460px; }
#green { float: right; width: 220px; }
    #green div { margin-bottom: 20px; }
#red { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; clear: left; }
    #red div { float: left; width: 220px; margin-right: 20px; }

.group:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="outer_wrapper" class="group">
    <div id="green" class="group">
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 0px;">6</div>
    </div>

    <div id="yellow">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>

    <div id="blue">
Sample text<br />
Sample text<br />
Sample text<br />
    </div>

    <div id="red">
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```